# Battleship Game-Exceptions

Tags: java

I'm doing a java program for an assignment, and one of the exceptions are that the user cannot input a value for a row or column that does not exist. i.e If the board was 5x7 and the user entered a column of value 10 the screen would print "Error: Invalid column" . However i'm unsure how to do this final exception and i need to submit it today. If anyone could help i'd really appreciate it! Here is my code for the makeGuess() function:

```
public void makeGuess(){
        //guesses is for keeping track of your guesses
        boolean cont=true;
        int rowGuess;
        int columnGuess;
        do{
        System.out.println("Enter a row to guess >");
        rowGuess = (input.nextInt()-1);
        if(rowGuess<=0){
            System.out.println("You did not enter a positive Integer.Please try again");
        cont=false;}
        else{
        cont=true;}
        }
        while (cont==false);


        do{
            System.out.println("Enter a column to guess >");
            columnGuess = (input.nextInt()-1);
            if(columnGuess <=0){
                System.out.println("You did not enter a positive integer.Please try again");
                cont=false;
            } else{
                cont=true;
            }
        }while(cont==false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the rest of your code works, you could simply alter your `if` statements to ensure the entry is valid.

Using the OR operator `||`:

```
if (columnGuess <= 0 || columnGuess >= 10){
    System.out.println("Error: invalid Column");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just as you have an if statement to test if the number is too small you also need to test if it is too big

```
public void makeGuess(){
    //guesses is for keeping track of your guesses
    boolean cont=true;
    int rowGuess;
    int columnGuess;
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter a row to guess >");
        rowGuess = (input.nextInt()-1);
        if(rowGuess<=0){
            System.out.println("You did not enter a positive Integer.Please try again");
            cont=false;
        }else if(rowGuess>7){
            System.out.println("You did not enter a small enough Integer.Please try again");
            cont=false;
        }else{
            cont=true;
        }
    }while (cont==false);


    do{
        System.out.println("Enter a column to guess >");
        columnGuess = (input.nextInt()-1);
        if(columnGuess <=0){
            System.out.println("You did not enter a positive integer.Pleasetry again");
            cont=false;
        }else if(columnGuess>5){
            System.out.println("You did not enter a small enough Integer.Please try again");
            cont=false;
        } else{
            cont=true;
        }
    }while(cont==false);
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this in my experience is to create your own exception

```
public class BadMoveException extends Exception {
  BadMoveException(Exception ex) {
    super(ex);
  }

  BadMoveException(String ex) {
    super(ex);
  }
}
```

Make `makeGuess` throw BadMoveException, and then for any of the invalid moves the user can make, you can create a BadMoveException with that, and print it in the catch { } block outside of makeGuess

```
while (!gameOver) {
  try {
    makeGuess();
  }
  catch (BadMoveException ex) {
    System.out.println("You tried to make an invalid move:" + ex.getMessage());
  }
}
```